# Why use the gun?

Tags: lateral-thinking

There was once a man named Ihav Iccups. One day, Ihav walked into a bar and asked the bartender for a cup of water. The bartender pulls out a gun and points it at the man. Ihav simply says 'Thank you', and walks out. Why?

Comment: Try looking at the Related posts on the side after you post a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy

> He had hiccups, the bartender scared him

Reasoning:

> He asked for a cup of water as that's known to cure hiccups. There are also a common (myth) that a sudden scare can cure hiccups as well. So the bartender just did the easiest thing for him.

and:

> His name is also Ihav Iccups (can be read **I hav*e* *h*iccups**)

Comment: read his full name again